# Parallel Sonar Scanner execution locking errors

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan

We're running the Sonar scanner (version 3.0.3.778) on Jenkins and creating a new project for each branch by using the sonar.projectKey and sonar.branch properties. Even though each branch creates a new project, we're still randomly getting errors saying that the project has another analysis in project already. It seems to be a bug in the scanner that it's tripping over its own lock when there should be separation between the projects. Note that we're also running version 5.6.6 of Sonar server and version 2.6.1 of the Jenkins SonarQube plugin. Any ideas?

```
03:51:40 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
03:51:40 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Another SonarQube analysis is already in progress for this project
03:51:40    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectLock.failAlreadyInProgress(ProjectLock.java:58)
03:51:40    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectLock.tryLock(ProjectLock.java:50)
03:51:40    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:109)
03:51:40    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:140)
03:51:40    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
03:51:40    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
03:51:40    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
03:51:40    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
03:51:40    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
03:51:40    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
03:51:40    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
03:51:40    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
03:51:40    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
03:51:40    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
03:51:40    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
03:51:40    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
03:51:40    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
03:51:40    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
03:51:40    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
03:51:40    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
03:51:40    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
03:51:40    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
03:51:40    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the version of SonarQube.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam - The version we're using is 5.6.6

Answer (score 2):

The scanner creates temporary files the project workspace in Jenkins. That's why we can't support concurrent analysis of the same physical set of files. You have to configure Jenkins so that it uses a different workspace for each branch.

Comment: In this case, we are already using a different workspace for each branch.